# Index CSV columns based on pattern

Tags: python, string, csv, replace, indexing

How do I get the indices from the columns containing a specific pattern?

For example, suppose I want to index which columns contain `#E` in this string:

```
,#E,D,,#E,,#,,#E,,,21#E,,#,,#DD,sd,,#,,##,
```

I want a result like:

```
 [1, 4, 8, 11]
```

So far I am puzzled with:

```
string = ',#E,D,,#E,,#,,#E,,,21#E,,#,,#DD,sd,,#,,##,'
new_string = re.sub('[^,#E]', '', string)
def positions(string, char):
    string_original = string
    list = []
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        if string[i] == char:
            list = list + [i]
            string = string_original[i + 1:]
    return list
```

Comment: is there stuff in between the commas like `#E,,#,` or is that the exact formatting?

Comment: Thank you for the spontaneous response. There "was" stuff, but I removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split on "," to get a list of values instead of string
2. Use a list comprehension to to iterate over the list passed to enumerate, which returns a list of tuples, like this [(0, "first string"), (1, "second string") ..]
3. Filter for elements that contain your string and place the index in the list

Assuming yourstring contains the columns:

```
matches = [i for i,x in enumerate(yourstring.split(',')) if "#E" in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure I got you, but here's an idea:

1. split the string by `,` to get a list of strings
2. select those indices that match a string (e.g. `#E`) within the list

---

```
>>> s = ',#E,D,,#E,,#,,#E,,,21#E,,#,,#DD,sd,,#,,##,'
>>> l = s.split(',')
>>> [i for i in range(len(l)) if '#E' in l[i]]
[1, 4, 8, 11]
```

or

```
>>> filter(lambda i: '#E' in l[i], range(len(l)))
[1, 4, 8, 11]
```